# How do I completely remove all Ruby gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to completely remove my Ruby and Rails installation.

After uninstalling Ruby with  `apt-get remove ruby1.9.1` I see that all the Ruby stuff like `ruby`, `rake` and `irb` from "/usr/bin" was removed but the gems remain here:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems
```

What's the best way to remove these? Again, I want to uninstall everything so I can try this install again.

```
rm -r /var/lib/gems/ ???
```

Comment: apt-get remove --purge might be what you are looking for

Comment: Does dpkg -S /path/to/gemfile show any package?

Answer (score 1):

After arm wrestling with this for most of the day, I uninstalled everything, installed [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) and then installed Ruby and Rails with RVM. Much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 'gem uninstall *' or --purge on apt-get remove.
However, you **can** safely

```
rm -r /var/lib/gems/
```